# Page Objects as variables in Ruby/Watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, pageobjects

I know that you can do something like this:

```
class MyPage  
    include PageObject
    text_field(:field_1, :id => 'field_1')  
    text_field(:field_2, :id => 'field_2')  
end

page = new MyPage  
page.field1 = 'foo'  
page.field2 = 'bar'
```

What I would like to do is be able to pass in a variable as the field using cucumber:

```
When(/^I set "([^"]*)" field to 'hello'$/) do |some_field|  
    page.some_field = 'hello'  
end
```

I know you can use `page.send(variable)` to call a method, but `page.send(variable) = 'hello'` does not work or other variations of that that I have tried so far. Is there a way to do what I am asking?

Answer (score 3):

Add an `=` to the method name when using send:

```
page.send("#{some_field}=", 'hello')
```